# change the unit in value after to_csv in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem when I was using pandas.
`trainData5` in below picture is my desired output.
 and you can check first row value at PNU column in blue box.

[image]

I open JIGA4.csv file after executing `to_csv`.
But I found out the unit is changed like in the blue box below picture .
what's wrong with my code?? help me plz.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the `to_csv()` code and the subsequent read? It's probably an issue with Excel's read, not pandas write. Open the CSV in a text editor and see what you get.

Comment: Oh sorry. The misunderstanding is caused by my english.
You could find the problem after comparing blue box in first picture and red box in second picture.
The last number of both first row in PNU columns are different

Comment: Oh ~ You're right. Correct value is in the text editor. How can i get correct value when opening the file using Excel??

Comment: Please don't post images of data or code.  Post the the actual text.

Comment: That's a whole different question which is Google-able.  Excel can be quite frustrating in its type assumptions.

Comment: @wwii - I wouldn't have been able to figure out the issue if not for the full image.  Think it was applicable in this case.

Comment: @wwii - sorry for my wrong question

Comment: @pshep123 - Dose Google-able means I can solve this problem googling?

Comment: Probably.  I'm mainly just saying it's a completely different question than you asked.  And because of that, I'd spend some time Googling an answer before posting another question on SO.

Answer (score 1):

I found it. So I answer my question.

I used this code.

```
trainData5.to_csv(r'D:\handling data\JIGA.txt', index=None, sep='|', mode='a')
```

instead of

```
trainData5.to_csv(r'D:\handling data\JIGA4.csv')
```

I opened .txt file using excel and then clicked split text using option(I 
don't know correct word).

set the delimiter for splitting the text.

I changed cell format(I don't know correct word) to text format.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks pshep123